# Call a method only once within XCUITest in Swift 4

Tags: swift, static-methods, xcuitest, xctestcase

My test suite contains some test cases. I have some private functions where I will check elements existence. Consider I have three test cases:

```
func test_1() {
    ...
    checkListViewElements()
    ...
}

func test_2() {
    ...
}

func test_3() {
    ...
    checkListViewElements()
    ...
}

private func checkListViewElements() {
    //Checking existence
}
```

Since I consider each test case as independent, the private function `checkListViewElements()` may get repeat within the test cases.

**Problem:**

- When I run the whole test suite, all the three test cases(*test_1*, *test_2* and *test_3*) will be executed.
- The private method `checkListViewElements()` will be called twice. This will  result with the increased amount of test suite completion time.

**What I wanted:**

- I have so many functions like `checkListViewElements()` within my code. I want them to run only once when I run the whole test suite. (Remember, for each test case, the application terminates and open freshly)

**What I tried:**

```
var tagForListViewElementsCheck = "firstTime" //Global variable

private func checkListViewElements() {
   if tagForListViewElementsCheck == "firstTime" {
      //Checking existence
      tagForListViewElementsCheck = "notFirstTime"
   }

   else {
      //Skip
   }
}
```

- If I use local variables as tag, it works fine. But here, I have to create each tag for each private method. I really hated that.
- I tried with `dispatch_once` and it seems not supported in Swift 4
- Then I tried with static structs by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203623/how-do-i-execute-code-once-and-only-once-in-swift). It also does not seems working.

If there is any other nice approach to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may use function `func setUp()`. Its call only once per suite. More info at [What is the purpose of XCTestCase's setUp method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038375/what-is-the-purpose-of-xctestcases-setup-method#21040654).